# Javascript Validation allow dot also at last third position

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my expression
I m checking for allow  only  0-9 digits

```
var alphaExp = /^[0-9]+$/;

 if (!txtRate.value.match(alphaExp)) {

              alert("Rate should be numeric.");
              txtRate.focus();
              return false;

          }
```

I want .(dot) also at last  third  position ..
if this is my expression 10000.00  (no alert generate for this)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
/^\d+(\.\d\d)?$/
```

Which says one ore more digits, optionally followed by a decimal point and two more digits. `\d` is just a shorthand for `[0-9]`

Answer (score 0):

Change your RexEx to this:

```
/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9])?$/
```